# Cassandra Trigger Exception: InvalidQueryException: table of additional mutation does not match primary update table

Tags: cassandra, database-trigger

i am using Cassandra Trigger on a table. I am following the example and loading trigger jar with 'nodetool reloadtriggers'. Then i am using

```
'CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger ON ..'
```

command from cqlsh to create trigger on my table. 
Adding an entry into that table , my audit table is being populated. 
But calling a method from within my Java application, which persists an entry into my table by using 
    'session.execute(BoundStatement)' i am getting this exception:

```
InvalidQueryException: table of additional mutation does not match primary update table
```

Why does the insertion into the table and the audit work when doing it directly with cqlsh and why does it fail when doing pretty much exactly the same with the Java application?

i am using this as AuditTrigger, very simplified(left out all of the other operations other than Row insertion:

```
   public class AuditTrigger implements ITrigger {
    private Properties properties = loadProperties();

    public Collection<Mutation> augment(Partition update) {
      String auditKeyspace = properties.getProperty("keyspace");
      String auditTable = properties.getProperty("table");

      CFMetaData metadata = Schema.instance.getCFMetaData(auditKeyspace, 
      auditTable);

      PartitionUpdate.SimpleBuilder audit = 
      PartitionUpdate.simpleBuilder(metadata, UUIDGen.getTimeUUID());



      if (row.primaryKeyLivenessInfo().timestamp() != Long.MIN_VALUE) {
                // Row Insertion
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                obj.put("message_id", update.metadata().getKeyValidator()
                .getString(update.partitionKey().getKey()));
                audit.row().add("operation", "ROW INSERTION");
          }
          audit.row().add("keyspace_name", update.metadata().ksName)
                     .add("table_name", update.metadata().cfName)
                     .add("primary_key", update.metadata().getKeyValidator()
                         .getString(update.partitionKey()
                         .getKey()));

    return Collections.singletonList(audit.buildAsMutation());
```

It seems like using BoundStatement, the trigger fails:

```
session.execute(boundStatement);
```

, using a regular cql queryString  works though.

```
session.execute(query)
```

We are using Boundstatement everywhere within our application though and cannot change that. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show code snippet that creates a mutation?

Comment: no comments or  information on this issue?